# Custom font doesn't work every where Android

Tags: android, android-fonts

For an app I am building right now I use a custom font.
On most phone's the custom font work just fine.

But on some phone's the font is not overriding all the textviews, I am absolutely clueless right now especially it works everywhere except in the black area

**The result I want:**

[HTC one mini 2, Android 4.4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf7Oc.png)

**The result I get:**

[Huawei Y300, Android 4.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiDOv.png)

[Unknown model ,Android 5.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrWjK.png)

**The Code:**

```
public final class FontsOverride {

public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
                                  String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
}

protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
                                  final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
        final Field staticField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
        staticField.setAccessible(true);
        staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**the XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewNewestArticleImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/emptychatuser"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNewestArticleTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sampleTitle"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It is just a normal textview the only difference between this one and al the other textview's is that the background color is different

Comment: Why do you use reflection for changing the color?

Comment: I just added the XML file of the view, I cant see anything wrong with it, also i added a extra image of the app on another phone where the font doesn't work in the black box and also not the toolbar on top

Answer (score 0):

It looks that all EMUI devices blocking all availability to change font. (
I am trying to find solution how to change the font, and use writing text to canvas, and also the same result. Only default font seted although i set my own TzpeFace.

I am not too happy from this result.

Comment: Did you ever find any solution?